# How to detect disconnection of Serial Port connection with javax.comm?

Tags: java, javax.comm

When a connection of SerialPorts (RS232) is interrupted/disconnected, how could I detect it and report it to the user?

As can happen in any moment, I suppose I should use a separate thread.

My connection type is: send msg - recieve msg

Comment: To clarify: are you asking how to detect whether the remote serial device (e.g. a terminal or modem or arduino or something) was removed, or how to detect if the serial port *itself* is disconnected (i.e. a usb<->serial adapter comes unplugged?) They are two very different scenarios. In my experience, many javax.comm implementations just flat-out crash (especially on windows) if the usb dongle is unplugged while the serial port is open. So detecting it won't be a problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RS232 does not detect the "state" of an physical connection. So I guess it is not possible to directly get an event in case of connect/disconnect. Probably the only way is to send something and detect if the answer is missing (or hearbeat or whatever...).

Comment: Good to know, thank you. Then I'm going to detect the disconnection if a send msg is not succesfull.

Comment: On a serial port, the 'send' will be successful anyway; you need send a message that generates a response, and then do something if you don't get the expected response.

Answer (score 1):

How much control do you have over the hardware or the remote device? You *might* be able to do something with the flow control lines: (i.e. if you are not using RTS/CTS flow control, but you can make your target device assert/deassert CTS, you might detect a change in CTS when the device is disconnected.) But be warned; this might work fine on one piece of hardware and not work on another due to hardware differences. In the general case, I agree with @MrD above that the most reliable/portable solution is to implement some heartbeat messaging (you send a message, wait for a response, like a TCP/IP PING), and generate a 'disconnect' event if you don't get a response within some timeout.